# How do I change Nav Bar Title in a UITableView Detail View when an event occurs?

Tags: uitableview, uiwebview, uinavigationbar

I have a UITableView that uses a UIWebView for its detail view. This detail view content has links. When a link is clicked, I want the nav bar title to change. How can I do this? I tried implementing the following UIWebView methods from my MainViewController and also in my AppDelegate.m file but neither fires when a link is clicked:

```
- (void)webViewDidStartLoad:(UIWebView *)webView{

  UIViewController *detailsViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

  detailsViewController.title = @"New Title Here";

}



- (void)webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType{

UIViewController *detailsViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

detailsViewController.title = @"New Title";

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
self.title = newTitle;
```

If you are pushing a new view controller (not clear from your question) put this in `viewDidLoad:`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try that once I am able to capture the click event from my UIWebView. That's really the crux of my issue, I think